# ImageMagick failing without throwing exception

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm trying to use ImageMagick - specifically, the Imagick() php class. I am having an issue with my process bombing out, but the my code isn't catching an exception.

```
$working_image = null; 
try
{  
    if ( strlen($source_data) == 0) 
       throw new Exception ("Image file has zero bytes.");

    $working_image = new \Imagick();
    if ( !$working_image->readImageBlob( $source_data ) )
    {
        throw new Exception("ImageMagick problem interpreting data");
    }

    if ( !$working_image->setImageFormat('jpeg') )
    {
        throw new Exception("ImageMagick problem setting image format");
    }
}
catch (ImageMagickException $ex)
{
    Logger::err("ImageMagickException processing image $ord for $mlsid/$mlsno, replacing with 'Invalid' image");
}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
    Logger::err("Exception processing image $ord for $mlsid/$mlsno, replacing with 'Invalid' image: " . $ex->getMessage() );
}
```

It seems that IMagick() is just printing out "Zero size image string passed" and not throwing an exception, at least not one that I have code for. All I see in my logs is:

```
Zero size image string passed
PIDFAIL queue_runner_loop pid=8912 exited with status code 1
```

The log messages in my catches are not being written out. This suggests to me that Imagick() is writing something to stdout and dieing.

Any suggestions? Is there another exception I can catch?

Comment: IM doesn't throw `ImageMagickException`, it throws `ImagickException`

Comment: I have also noticed this error showing up in the logs, again, not caught: 
   "no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/358"

Comment: Thanks for the updated exception, but it's still not catching it, and still writing the "Zero sized image string passed" message. But wouldn't any exception thrown be derived from the Exception class, and therefore the second catch grab it even if I had the wrong one before?

Comment: what format is this input image? "no delegate" implies imagick can't figure out how to handle it (e.g. it's a pdf and ghostscript isn't available)

Comment: I wish I knew. I'm processing 100's of images a minute right now, and since I can't catch an exception from ImageMagick, I can't have the logs tell me what image is failing. I'm going to have to get dirty with the logs now. I'll hopefully find that in a bit.

Comment: Ok, I have isolated a couple of the files throwing the "no decode delegate for this image " error... and of course, if I try to "identify" it, I get the same error. "file <filename>" just says data. If I dump the first bit out, it looks like it's a PNG, though the header says "jpeg". I'm guessing that reading a png as an imageblob, and then forcing it to be by a jpeg via setImageFormat might be the problem?